# Raspberry Service permissions not working

Tags: bash, .net-core, raspberry-pi

i have trouble with permissions in my service.

```
[Unit]
Description=TwinHubClient

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/TwinHubClient
ExecStart=/home/pi/TwinHubClient/TwinHubClient
Restart=always
# Restart service after 60 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=60
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-TwinHubClient
User=pi
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

after starting service, i've got a failure in log:

```
SQLite Error 8: 'attempt to write a readonly database'.
```

if I execute with same user manually, everything is working fine.
I tryed different permissionsettings 775, 644 without succeed. Any ideas whats going wrong here?

Comment: Does `777` make it work? If it does, but `775` doesn't, then it's not running as the user or as a member of the group that owns the resource.

Comment: Yeah! With 777 service is running! I'll try to change the user

Comment: Also, check out: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks guys! After changing user and group, everything is working.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem description**

After starting my bash script, i downloading files and extracting them to my defined folder. After extracting succeed, I copied my service to */etc/systemd/system/xxxx.service*, enabled it and starting it. After few seconds, service is crashed. In *journalctl* you can see the following exception:

```
SQLite Error 8: 'attempt to write a readonly database'.
```

If i starting my programm manually, everything is working fine! So, tryed to change permissions to my executing folder where database exists. 644 and 775 doesn't work! After changing to 777 and restarting service, everything is working like expected!

**Solution**

I found out, that I changed the permissions but never changed the owner and group of my folder! Both are as *root/root*. After changing to *pi:pi* with command

```
sudo chown pi:pi <folder>
```

and also

```
sudo chmod 644 <folder>
```

My Service is working with user 'pi' like expected! So my mistake was the wrong ownership of directory where database exists.

Thanks!